# Wallet didn't include fee, transaction stuck on unconfirmed

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

My wallet has always automatically included a transaction fee everytime I do a transaction, but this time it didn't and I dont know why. I did everything like I always do and I haven't changed anything that I know of.
So now my transaction have been unconfirmed for 1 day and I've read it's because it didn't include a fee. What should I do now? I can't wait for up to a week for it to get cancelled. :( Need to get them back and redo the transaction or somehow get them confirmed ASAP.

This is the transaction:
https://blockchain.info/tx/af34c93bac12c62f47415e1a419267a2e836e56f4b2c2d170a350f82e4ed639f

Thanks!

Comment: You can either wait, or try to double-spend it: [Speeding up confirmation by double-spending a transaction stuck in mempool](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37509/5406). This does require some technical expertise and may cause loss of money if performed incorrectly. However, your transaction shows a high priority, so it should go through eventually.

Comment: Double spend it, otherwise it will never get "cancelled" you could wait 8 months.. The only way is double spending :) Obviously this q is too old but for newcomers with the same problem!